# cannot find module model with sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Im trying to do a simple connection between postgres and sql using sequelize, but i get a error where i can't require the model folder, in this tutorial he can require the model folder and add it to the sync, like model.sync, what i need to do.

so this is my app code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var debug = require('debug')('express-sequelize');
var http = require('http');
var model= require('./models');


var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
  /**
   * Create HTTP server.
   */
var server = http.createServer(app);

model.sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  /**
   * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
   */
  server.listen(port, function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
  });
  server.on('error', onError);
  server.on('listening', onListening);
});

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

my model sequelize code:

```
"use strict";

var fs        = require("fs");
var path      = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config    = require(path.join(__dirname, '..','config', 'config.json'))[env];


if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL,config);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}
var db        = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
     return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file.indexOf('sequelize.js') < 0);
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

my folder structure:
[image: folderStructure]

Answer (score 3):

You have to rename your models/sequelize.js to models/index.js in able to require models folder as module.

Comment: but why? i actually did that to put the project working, but i really prefered the sequelize name isn't that possible?

Comment: This is related to how nodejs handle require() call. 
In your example, you have: var model = require('./models'); 
What does it mean for node? 
First it will look for file named "models.js". You don't have such file, so, it go to step 2 and  will look for folder named 'models' and a file named 'index.js' in it.
If it exist it will require it like if you wrote require('./models/index.js'); 
If you want to stick with your names, you have  to change your require() call to something like: var models = require('./models/sequelize');

Comment: But I suggest to use index.js which by convention is used as 'loader' if your module consist of several files.